# How to plot S&P 500 and Sotheby's Time Series in one ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

I am downloading with the quantmod package the S&P 500 time series and the Sotheby's stock:

```
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

env1 = new.env()
getSymbols("^GSPC", env = env1, src ="yahoo", from = as.Date("1988-06-01"),to = as.Date("2013-05-29"))
GSPC = env1$GSPC
gspc.df = data.frame(date=time(GSPC), coredata(GSPC))

env2 = new.env()
getSymbols("BID", env = env2, src ="yahoo", from = as.Date("1988-06-01"),to = as.Date("2013-05-29"))
BID = env2$BID
sothebys.df = data.frame(date=time(BID), coredata(BID))
```

My objective is to merge or melt the Adjusted Prices together and plot them with ggplot. However, I have problems with the df frame:

```
t = as.Date(0:9128, origin="1988-06-01")  
y1 = gspc.df$GSPC.Adjusted
y2 = sothebys.df$BID.Adjusted
df = data.frame(t=t, values=c(y2,y1), type=rep(c("Bytes", "Changes"), each=9129))

g = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=t, y=values)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(type ~ ., scales="free") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10") +
  ylab("Log values")
g
```

When I try to execute the df = data... line I get an error concerning the number of rows. How can I melt or merge the data, so that I can use them for the combined ggplot?

## EDIT

The graph works fine. In the last step I included the recession bars into the graph. The following code produces the recession bars including the normalized times seres:

```
recessions.df = read.table(textConnection(
  "Peak, Trough
  1857-06-01, 1858-12-01
  1860-10-01, 1861-06-01
  1865-04-01, 1867-12-01
  1869-06-01, 1870-12-01
  1873-10-01, 1879-03-01
  1882-03-01, 1885-05-01
  1887-03-01, 1888-04-01
  1890-07-01, 1891-05-01
  1893-01-01, 1894-06-01
  1895-12-01, 1897-06-01
  1899-06-01, 1900-12-01
  1902-09-01, 1904-08-01
  1907-05-01, 1908-06-01
  1910-01-01, 1912-01-01
  1913-01-01, 1914-12-01
  1918-08-01, 1919-03-01
  1920-01-01, 1921-07-01
  1923-05-01, 1924-07-01
  1926-10-01, 1927-11-01
  1929-08-01, 1933-03-01
  1937-05-01, 1938-06-01
  1945-02-01, 1945-10-01
  1948-11-01, 1949-10-01
  1953-07-01, 1954-05-01
  1957-08-01, 1958-04-01
  1960-04-01, 1961-02-01
  1969-12-01, 1970-11-01
  1973-11-01, 1975-03-01
  1980-01-01, 1980-07-01
  1981-07-01, 1982-11-01
  1990-07-01, 1991-03-01
  2001-03-01, 2001-11-01
  2007-12-01, 2009-06-01"), sep=',',
colClasses=c('Date', 'Date'), header=TRUE)

recessions.trim = subset(recessions.df, Peak >= min(gspc.df$date))
g.gspc = ggplot(data = df2) + geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = GSPC, colour = "blue")) + geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Sothebys, colour = "red")) + theme_bw()
g.gspc = g.gspc + geom_rect(data=recessions.trim, aes(xmin=Peak, xmax=Trough, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='pink', alpha=0.4)
plot(g.gspc)
```

[image: Normalized SP500 and Sothebys share including recession bars]

Thank you very much for your assistance / teaching. I am quite new to programming and R, thanks for helping me to improve :)

By the way, if somebody has an idea to further improve this solution, please comment! Thx

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The exact error might point to the problem directly, without having to reproduce your example. So could you edit your post to include the exact error message?

Comment: Also, this recent post might help you with what you're trying to do. If I'm not mistaken, it even uses the same datasets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703204/overlap-time-series-with-different-dataframes/16703580#16703580

Comment: Dear Thunk, the exact error message is in German. My problem is exactly this line:
df = data.frame(t=t, values=c(y2,y1), type=rep(c("Bytes", "Changes"), each=9129))

Comment: Fehler in data.frame(t = t, values = c(y2, y1), type = rep(c("Bytes", "Changes"),  :
  Argumente implizieren unterschiedliche Anzahl Zeilen: 9129, 12594, 18258

Basically, it says different amount of rows: 9129...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data from Sotheby's has slightly fewer observations than the data from the S&P.  If you remove the dates from S&P that do not appear in Sotheby's, then it works fine.  You were doing some weird things in defining your dataframe as well, so I fixed that.

```
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

# import 
env1 = new.env()
getSymbols("^GSPC", env = env1, src ="yahoo", from = as.Date("1988-06-01"),to = as.Date("2013-05-29"))
GSPC = env1$GSPC
gspc.df = data.frame(date=time(GSPC), coredata(GSPC))

env2 = new.env()
getSymbols("BID", env = env2, src ="yahoo", from = as.Date("1988-06-01"),to = as.Date("2013-05-29"))
BID = env2$BID
sothebys.df = data.frame(date=time(BID), coredata(BID))

# find which dates are in GSPC but not in Sotheby's
bad.dates <- sothebys.df$date[-which(gspc.df$date %in% sothebys.df$date)]

# remove the 'bad dates' from the dataframe so that both stocks have representative observations
# from each date
gspc.df <- gspc.df[-which(gspc.df$date %in% bad.dates),]

# verify the lengths
length(gspc.df) == length(sothebys.df)

# build the dataframe with dates and stock prices to be used in graphing
df = data.frame(Date = gspc.df$date,
                GSPC = gspc.df$GSPC.Adjusted,
                Sothebys = sothebys.df$BID.Adjusted)

# plot prices over time
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date)) + geom_line(aes(y = GSPC), colour = "blue") +
                                   geom_line(aes(y = Sothebys), colour = "red")
```

You should definitely think about looking at just the day-to-day price changes, which is a common practice when comparing stocks.  The difference in trading volume between an index and a particular security is so great that you can't learn much by looking at the chart you requested.  I use the normalization function below occasionally.  It isn't perfect for this situation (it scales everything to a range of 0 to 1), but I'll leave it up to you to standardize your data properly.  In the mean time, the following code will give you a good idea of how they compare:

```
NormalizeVector <- function(x) {
  NormCalc <- function(x) {
    (x - min(x, na.rm=TRUE))/(max(x,na.rm=TRUE) - min(x, na.rm=TRUE))
  }
  if (class(x) %in% c("integer", "numeric")) {
    norm.val <- NormCalc(x)
  }
  else norm.val <- x
  return(norm.val)
}

df2 = as.data.frame(lapply(df, NormalizeVector))

# plot normalized prices over time
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Date)) + geom_line(aes(y = GSPC), colour = "blue") +
                                   geom_line(aes(y = Sothebys), colour = "red")
```

[image: stockplots]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, zap2008! I had just time to quickly read it, but it matches perfectly what I am trying to do! I will get back to you after I had time to check the changes you made.

Comment: Dear zap2008, I checked the coding differences. The bad.dates line is great. I just had no clue how to code it. Moreover, big thanks for sharing the code for the normalization vector with me.

Comment: Dear zap, finally I try to add recession bars to your normalized plot. I would be very happy, if you have a further look. Have a great Friday / weekend, Chris

Comment: looks like you figured that one out on your own.